# Can't wrap an HTML structure around an element

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, dom

I want to take all the elements with the `table` tag and wrap an HTML structure around it so the tables should become responsive, but it is not working for some reason. 
Could you please tell me what am I doing wrong and why it is not working?

```
AfterContentChecked() {
    this.el = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
    this.wrapper = document.createElement('div.table-responsive');
    this.el.parentNode.insertBefore(this.wrapper, this.el);
    this.wrapper.appendChild(this.el);
  }
```

Comment: Please check angular lifecycle hooks - https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#onchanges     I think you need to use replace `AfterContentChecked()` with `ngAfterViewChecked()`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: direct dom manipulation is strongly discouraged in Angular. what you are doing is very bad practice in angular. read about "dom manipulation techniques in angular" moreover explain what exactly you are trying to accomplish and show relevant pieces of code so that people can guide you.

Comment: there shouldn't be direct dom manipulation in angular. You can create a directive that will sit on the container of the table. In the container, you can then set the style.width, style.height property on the table container. make sure that the table will stretch out to the container only.

Comment: Why would you wish to do such a thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ngAfterContentChecked() {
    const el = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
    this.doItOnce = true;
    if (el.length && this.doItOnce) {
      this.doItOnce = !this.doItOnce;
      for (let i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
        const element = el.item(i);
        const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
        wrapper.className = 'table-responsive';
        element.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, element);
        wrapper.appendChild(element);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: `ngAfterContentChecked` will work. but the best place is `ngAfterViewInit`

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is not **`AfterContentChecked`**. In should be **`ngAfterContentChecked`**.
But use **`ngAfterViewInit`** life cycle hook instead **`ngAfterContentChecked`** for your implementation. Add `id` property to `table` and use **`getElementById`** instead **`getElementsByTagName`**. Do not set `table-responsive` class at once. First create `div` element then add the `class`.

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <table id="table" class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Country</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Sudarshana</td>
          <td>Sri Lanka</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.el = document.getElementById('table');
    this.wrapper = document.createElement('div');
    this.wrapper.classList.add('table-responsive');
    this.el.parentNode.insertBefore(this.wrapper, this.el);
    this.wrapper.appendChild(this.el);
  }
```

**[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-56859088?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: Actually, the problem was that `this.el` was undefined. Plus, I didn't need to change `ngAfterContentChecked`. I will write full solution code in the comments.
P.S. Thanks for helping!